# Detect a special class during a each into jQuery

Tags: jquery, each

How can I check if all my `span` elements has a special class (a, b or c) ?

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <span class="a b"><span>
            <span class="b"><span>
            <span class="b c"><span>
            <span class="a c"><span>
            <span class="c"><span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
  var class_to_search = 'a';
   $('#form > span:not(.'+ class_to_search +')').each( function(i) {
       $(this).addClass('hide');
  });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Initially you code above wont work because there is no html attribute with the ID `#save-form-datas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is when you determine which class you want to show - hide all elements (spans) and then showthe ones that have that class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selection").change(function(){
    var elementToShow = $(this).val();
    $('#contentRow span').hide();
    $('#contentRow .' + elementToShow).show();
   })
});
```

```css
#contentRow span{display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <label for = "selection">Select the element you wish to show</label>
  <select id = "selection">
     <option selected disabled></option>
     <option>a</option>
     <option>b</option>
     <option>c</option>
  </select>

  <hr/>

   <div class="row">
        <div id= "contentRow" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <span class="a b">test 1 (contains classes a & b)</span>
            <span class="b">test 2 (contains class b)</span>
            <span class="b c">test 3 (contains classes b & c)</span>
            <span class="a c">test 4 (contains classes a & C)</span>
            <span class="c">test 5 (contains class c)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a bit to show the difference but you can do scoped searches in the dom with jquery by doing your search selectors `.a` with a sub selection `#form` so it can be found quicker without traversing the entire dom each pass.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var class_to_search = '.a';
    $(class_to_search,'#form').each(function(idx,e) {
      $(e).addClass('show');
    });
  });
```

```css
.a,.b,.c{
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.show{
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <span class="a b"></span>
      <span class="b"></span>
      <span class="b c"></span>
      <span class="a c"></span>
      <span class="c"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Initial post was to add a class of show.. the edit is to add the class of 'hide' if it doesn't have the "class_to_search" so this answer may be invalid now.